# Hardware listing utility which visualizes components?

Tags: data-visualization, hardware

I'm looking for a utility which probes my hardware (or uses the output of another hardware probing utility, such as lshw on Linux or HWInfo on Windows), and visualizes hardware components in a way similar to where I would see them within my case, i.e. lets me peer into a "virtual PC case" and see the motherboard with its slots, the cards occupying slots, etc.

**Notes:**

- I'm not looking for an exact reconstruction in any way, i.e. a motherboard could basically be a rectangle with some inner rectangles representing USB hubs, CPU sockets, PCI sockets etc.
- Preferably gratis and open-source, but commercial software might also be interesting.
- Price range < $1,000, but that's just throwing an arbitrary number.
- Should run under Linux (or at least Windows as a second priority).
- Must work on x86_64 CPUs.